# Different Security Permissions for Multiple Assemblies on Same AppDomain

Tags: .net, security, appdomain

Is it possible to load multiple assemblies into a new AppDomain and apply different `PermissionSet` to each?

Say, allow one of the assemblies to write to disk by granting it an unrestricted `FileIOPermission` and denying such permission to the other(s).

If it's possible. How?

### Update

P.S. I'm creating instances of types out of DLL's not executing exes, so I'm using `Load` and `CreateInstanceAndUnwrap` instead of `ExecuteAssembly`.

### Update

I tried (and failed) providing evidence with the load method with the following code:

```
Dim domain As AppDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("AssembliesDomain")
Dim protectedSet As New PermissionSet(PermissionState.None)

protectedSet.AddPermission(New SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.Execution))
protectedSet.AddPermission(New IsolatedStorageFilePermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted))
protectedSet.PermitOnly()

domain.Load(protectedAssembly, New Evidence(Nothing, {protectedSet}))
domain.Load(unprotectedAssembly, New Evidence(Nothing, {protectedSet}))

Console.WriteLine(domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(protectedAssembly, protectedAssembly & ".Actions").Sum(1, 2))
Console.WriteLine(domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(unprotectedAssembly, unprotectedAssembly & ".Actions").Sum(1, 2))
Console.ReadLine()
```

Comment: The code you have seems right. Are you using ClickOnce deployment? You need to specify "This is a full trust application" in your project settings.

Comment: Isn't ClickOnce asp? This is a desktop application.

Comment: ClickOnce is a deployment technology that helps you deploy your Windows Form App or WPF App by clicking a hyperlink on a page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce. If you're not using ClickOnce, then you can perhaps use [PermView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06251f13(v=VS.80).aspx) tool to check what permissions your app has. I believe you need to grant the `UIPermission` to your assembly (you can do it via `AssemblyInfo.cs` file too).

Comment: @Mrchief I'll get into it tonight :)

Comment: @PedroC88: Which version of .NET are you targeting?

Comment: Hey, what do you have in `protectedAssmebly` and `unprotectedAssembly`? I'm trying to set it up on my side. Meanwhile, checkout this article: http://www.reliablesoftware.com/articles/UnderstandingSecurityActions.html

Comment: Also try adding this line: `protectedSet.AddPermission(new UIPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted));`

Comment: @Mrchief write an answer and win that bounty! :) Fixed.

Comment: As to ProtectedAssembly and UnprotectedAssembly they basically have the same code, an implementation of SUM(a, b). One writes the result to the IsolatedStorage, the other to my desktop. The idea is to ensure that I can properly keep a DLL from writing to disk unless it does so in it's Isolated Storage section.

Comment: Could you explain why I need the UIPermission for this?

Comment: @Mrchief let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2345/discussion-between-pedroc88-and-mrchief)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line (to get around the exception you're getting):

```
protectedSet.AddPermission(new UIPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted));
```

Helpful article: http://www.reliablesoftware.com/articles/UnderstandingSecurityActions.html

Answer (score 0):

You could either specify custom Evidence object when using the Assembly.Load method to instantiate one of your custom Assemblies, or have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostsecuritypolicyresolver.aspx)

Comment: I'm not doing this on ASP, I'm trying this on a desktop app. I had already tried using the evidence with `Load` but I get a `SecurityException` stating that stating that "The request for the permission of type `System.Security.Permissions.UIPermission` failed". See Updated answer.